# Getting equal symbol expected while using jstl

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I am getting

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/AllClientBatchDetails.jsp(54,103) equal symbol expected

And here is the jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" import="java.util.*%>   
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>   
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>   
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>  
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>  


<html:html xhtml="true">   
<head>   
<title><bean:message key="progressReporter.successpage.title"/></title>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">    
<html:base/>   
</head>   
<body>  
 <c:choose>   
  <c:when test="${empty batchProgressMetricsList}">  
   <font color=<bean:message key="error.font.color" />   size=<bean:message key="error.font.size" />>  
     <bean:message key="error.no.active.batch" />  
   </font>  
   <br/>  
  </c:when>  
  <c:otherwise>  
   <h4><bean:message key="table.header" /></h4>  
   <table border=<bean:message key="table.border.size" />>  
    <tr>  
     <th><bean:message  key="table.client.id.header" /></th>  
     <th><bean:message key="table.total.session.used" /></th>  
     <th><bean:message key="table.total.time.elapsed" /></th>  
     <th><bean:message key="table.imnts.completed" /></th>  
     <th><bean:message key="table.imnts.remaining" /></th>  
     <th><bean:message key="table.cores.allocated" /></th>  
     <th><bean:message key="table.time.remaining" /></th>  
    </tr>  
    <c:forEach var="aggregatedBatchProgressMetrics" items="${batchProgressMetricsList}">  
     <tr>  
      <td class="tdcenter">${aggregatedBatchProgressMetrics["clientId"]}</td>        
      <td class="tdcenter">${fn:substringBefore(aggregatedBatchProgressMetrics["sessionStats"]["sessionUsedTime"]/60000, '.')}mins${fn:substringBefore((aggregatedBatchProgressMetrics["sessionStats"]["sessionUsedTime"] % 60000)/1000, '.')}secs </td>  
      <td class="tdcenter">${fn:substringBefore(aggregatedBatchProgressMetrics["sessionStats"]["totalElapsedTime"]/60000, '.')}mins${fn:substringBefore((aggregatedBatchProgressMetrics["sessionStats"]["totalElapsedTime"] % 60000)/1000, '.')}secs</td>  
      <td class="tdcenter">${aggregatedBatchProgressMetrics["instrumentStats"]["totalImntsCompleted"]}</td>  
      <td class="tdcenter">${aggregatedBatchProgressMetrics["instrumentStats"]["totalImntsRemaining"]}</td>  
      <td class="tdcenter">${aggregatedBatchProgressMetrics["numberOfCores"]}</td>  
      <td class="tdcenter">${fn:substringBefore(aggregatedBatchProgressMetrics["sessionStats"]["sessionRemainingTime"]/60000, '.')}mins${fn:substringBefore((aggregatedBatchProgressMetrics["sessionStats"]["sessionRemainingTime"] % 60000)/1000, '.')}secs</td>  
      <br/>  
       <table>  
        <tr>  
         <th>session Id</th>  
         <th>taskId</th>  
         <th>task start time</th>  
         <th>task end time</th>  
        </tr>        
        ${aggregatedBatchProgressMetrics["batchMetricsList"][0]}  
        ${aggregatedBatchProgressMetrics["batchMetricsList"][1]}  
        ${aggregatedBatchProgressMetrics["batchMetricsList"][2]}  

        <c:forEach var="batchProgressMetrics" items="${aggregatedBatchProgressMetrics["batchMetricsList"]}">  
         <tr>  
          <td class="tdcenter">${batchProgressMetrics["taskStats"]["sessionId"]}</td>  
          <td class="tdcenter">${batchProgressMetrics["taskStats"]["taskId"]}</td>  
          <td class="tdcenter">${batchProgressMetrics["taskStats"]["taskStartTime"]}</td>  
          <td class="tdcenter">${batchProgressMetrics["taskStats"]["taskEndTime"]}</td>  
         </tr>  
        </c:forEach>          
       </table>  
      <br/>  
     </tr>  
    </c:forEach>  
   </table>  
  </c:otherwise>  
 </c:choose>  
<html:link page="/ProgressReporterForm.jsp">Go Back</html:link>   
</body>   
</html:html>
```

I have request attribute set to batchProgressMetricsList and its an array list of an object called. I have AggregatedBatchProgressMetrics. Inside `aggregatedBatchProgressMetrics` i have a method called `getBatchMetricsList` which return an arraylist of object called BatchProgressMetrics. If i run it without the nested `c:forEach` tag, it would just run fine, but if i include the nested one it just fails. Can somebody please help me?

Thanks in advance.
Almas

Comment: Don't try and XML-escape your code samples, SO's editor can do a much better job. What you've posted is unreadable.

Answer (score 16):

Try changing this:

```
items="${aggregatedBatchProgressMetrics["batchMetricsList"]}"
```

to this:

```
items="${aggregatedBatchProgressMetrics['batchMetricsList']}"
```

Comment: @Almas than why is this not marked as an answer? It would be nice.

Answer (score 6):

Replace

```
<c:forEach var="batchProgressMetrics" items="${aggregatedBatchProgressMetrics["batchMetricsList"]}">
```

by

```
<c:forEach var="batchProgressMetrics" items="${aggregatedBatchProgressMetrics['batchMetricsList']}">
```

The doublequote was closing the `items` value too soon which resulted in invalid EL. You should have spotted this soon enough when using an editor with decent sytnax highlighting (like here on SO :) ).